# implementing admin section of site as subfolder

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, design-patterns

[image: Directory structure]

I have this directory structure for my application, what I need is to use **subfolder admin** for website administration purposes, admin folder has it's separate login, roles based authentication system and has nothing to do with main site. As you can see it has separate web.config for authentication purpose. I want users to access admin section using `http://localhost/library/admin` but when I implement form-based authentication in admin's web.config it gives me `MachineToApplication` Error, I tried converting it to application then it worked fine, but I am not able to use App_Code Classes then ! **I have this feeling that I am doing it wrong and confused about having this subfolder implementation** wrong as admin is totally a separate application. Please suggest If this is right or how can I improve this.
Note: I am intended to use same **App_Code Folder and Database** for main site and admin both

Answer (score 0):

For a quick win with your project setup, could you not create a separate Admin DB on the same DB server and just use the alternate connection string in the /admin/ section? Set up membership on both and then you have a completely isolated admin DB from the rest of the site.

Comment: I don't have any issue separating databases, but I am not having problem with the database at all and it's a mandate for me to use same database, what I wanted is to run separate applications but still using same App_Code Classes, but that not seems to be possible, now I have separated App_code for both applications and thing seems to be working . anyways thanx for your support